# Load Assembly with needed References in defined directory

Tags: .net, filesystems, .net-assembly

**Situation**

When loading any module (exe files) Assembly from file, an error occours that the needed references of this assembly are not found. 
If I start the assembly in Windows explorer all works well.

There seems to be a problem with needed references, because they are in a subfolder.

The structure looks like that

```
..\MainApplication.exe 
..\Plugins\Plugin01.exe (needs Interactivity.dll) 
..\Plugins\Interactivity.dll
```

**Question**

How to tell that the needed Interactivity.dll reference is not in the root folder of the main application but in the same folder as the plugin?

**Code sample**

Dim TAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly
TAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\MyProject\Plugins\Plugin01.exe")

**Original Error message**

```
{"Zeilennummer \"33\" und Zeilenposition \"18\" von \"Bei der Initialisierung von 
\"Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonApplicationMenu\" 
wurde eine Ausnahme ausgelöst.\"."}
```

.

```
Die Datei oder Assembly "Microsoft.Windows.Shell, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. 
Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

Comment: See the static  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event

Comment: Interesting. As I understand, there is no possibility in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` to change any path there, just possible to catch the loading event of assemblies.

Comment: You can load and return the assembly in that event.

Comment: The MainApplication.exe loads the Plugin01.exe and in the Plugin01.exe I am not able to link to Interactivity.dll. I've tried now for more than one hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the needed assembly as an embedded resource in your program then use the AssemblyResolve event to pass the assembly into your program.  Just make sure that you statically link to the actual .dll at development time so that you can get designer and intellisense  support.